# Select K random lines from a text file

Tags: c++, algorithm, random

This is an extension of the original question of selecting a random line from a text of X lines where the probability of the text line selected is 1/X. The trick is to select the Jth line if you query a random variable Y with a range of [0,1) and it returns a value less than 1/J.

Now in this new version of the problem we have to select K random lines where K is less than X. I believe the probability for each line should be K/X.

I'm stuck on how to extend the original solution to K lines. Is it possible? any explanations would be great.

Comment: wouldn't you just apply the original solution `k` times?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be solved using a generalization of the original algorithm.  The intuition is as follows: maintain a list of k candidate lines from the file, which are initially seeded to the first k lines.  Then, from that point forward, upon seeing the nth line of the file:

- Choose a random value x between 1 and n, inclusive.
- If x > k, ignore this element.
- Otherwise, replace element x with the nth line of the file.

The proof that this correctly samples each element with probability k / n, where n is the total number of lines in the file, is as follows.  Assume that n ≥ k.  We prove by induction that each element has probability k / n of being picked by showing that after seeing z elements, each of those elements has probability k / z of being chosen.  In particular, this means that after seeing n elements, each has probability k / n as required.

As our inductive basis, if we see exactly k elements, then each is picked.  Thus the probability of being chosen is k / k, as required.

For the inductive step, assume that for some z ≥ k, each of the first z elements have been chosen with probability k / z and consider the (z + 1)st element.  We choose a random natural number in the range [1, z + 1].  With probability k / (z + 1), we decide to choose this element, then evict some old element.  This means that the new element is chosen with probability k / (z + 1).  For each of the z original elements, the probability that it is chosen at this point is then the probability that we had chosen it after the first z elements were inspected (probability k / z, by our inductive hypothesis), and the probability that we retain it is z / (z + 1), since we replace it with probability 1 / (z + 1).  Thus the new probability that it is chosen is (k / z) (z / (z + 1)) = k / (z + 1).  Thus all of the first z + 1 elements are chosen with probability k / (z + 1), completing the induction.

Moreover, this algorithm runs in O(n) time and uses only O(k) space, meaning that the runtime is independent of the value of k.  To see this, note that each iteration does O(1) work, and there are a total of O(n) interations.

If you're curious, I have an implementation of this algorithm as a C++ STL-style algorithm **[available here on my personal site](http://keithschwarz.com/interesting/code/?dir=random-sample)**.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This line may need updating " size_t index = rng() % (count + 1);" Its not wrong per say though I believe there are better ways of quantizing random values.

Answer (score -2):

First select the first element randomly out of the X lines using the first algorithm. Then select the second out of the remaining X-1 lines. Run this process K times.

The probability of any given set of K lines is `(X choose K)`. I'll leave it up to you to verify that this algorithm gives the desired uniform distribution.